# android: db.query syntax for multiple conditions

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a table in the database like this:

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"   + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_SUB_CATEGORY + " TEXT, " + KEY_AMOUNT + " REAL, "
        + KEY_NOTE + " TEXT " + " );");
```

I want to get the trans_amount values for KEY_CATEGORY = ("Income" or "Expense" )
and KEY_DATE  = "March 2013".

How Can I query to get it? I am currently using

```
db.ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
   new String[] { KEY_AMOUNT } , " ( " 
   + KEY_CATEGORY + " = ? OR " 
   + KEY_CATEGORY + " = ? ) AND " + KEY_DATE + " = ? " , 
  new String[] { " VariableExpenses " , " FixedExpenses ", " March/08/2013 " }, 
  null, null, null, null);
```

But I am not getting the KEY_AMOUNT values. Am I missing something in the query?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without seeing some sample data.

Comment: `=` is unforgiving, do you really pad all of your data with spaces `" March/08/2013 "` or is it `"March/08/2013"` or perhaps it's your example of `"March 2013"`?

Comment: Thank you! It was the spaces that was giving me no data. I was adding unnecessary space in the query.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to store your dates as an INTEGER as milliseconds since epoch (returned by `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` or `date.getTime()`) or as separate month/year columns if you only care about month and year rather than text as it appears you are not getting any rows back due to the formatting of the date: Your query says "March/08/2013" while your say you want "March 2013".